# How to specify array row height with slashbox?

Tags: tables

I'm having issues with `\backslashbox`. As you can see from the picture, it's, for lack of a better word, ugly. I want to make the row height smaller to force the slashbox smaller as well. I tried using `\arraystretch`, but that didn't affect the slashbox. Is there any way I *can* make it looks nicer while still using `\backslashbox`?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mbox D^{\frac 1 2}_{mm^\prime}=\begin{array}{r | r r}
\mbox{\backslashbox{$m$\kern-1em}{\kern-1em$m^{\prime\prime}$}}& \frac 1 2 & -\frac 1 2 \\ \hline
\frac 1 2 & a & b \\
-\frac 1 2 & c & d
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you go for a smaller row height you will force the `m''` down and it will collide with the backslash line. The only solution I can think of is to reduce the font size of the `m` and `m''` cells.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something that worked for your particular arguments.  And then, in order to try to make it work for alternate things in the `\bsbox` (backslash box), I introduced the `\refA` and `\refB` concept in the MWE, wherein I place the `\bsbox` arguments in boxes that are the same size as what worked originally.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\refA{$m$}
\def\refB{$m^{\prime\prime}$}
\newcommand\bsbox[2]{%
  \raisebox{-1pt}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\rotatebox{45}{\rule[-.5em]{.2pt}{3em}}}{%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \setstackgap{L}{.5\baselineskip}%
  \kern-1pt\makebox[\widthof{\refA}][r]{#1}\stackon{}{\smash{\makebox[\widthof{\refB}]{#2}}}\kern1pt%
  }%
  \kern-5.5pt}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mbox D^{\frac 1 2}_{mm^\prime}=\begin{array}{r | r r}
\mbox{\normalsize\bsbox{$m$}{$m^{\prime\prime}$}}& \frac 1 2 & -\frac 1 2 \\ \hline
\frac 1 2 & a & b \\
-\frac 1 2 & c & d
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mbox D^{\frac 1 2}_{mm^\prime}=\begin{array}{r | r r}
\mbox{\normalsize\bsbox{$m^2$}{$m_{2}$}}& \frac 1 2 & -\frac 1 2 \\ \hline
\frac 1 2 & a & b \\
-\frac 1 2 & c & d
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ErikaH I appreciate your thanks.  And I welcome you to the site.  Seeing as you are a new user here, I will mention that a preferred way of saying "thanks" is to click the up arrow by an answer to "upvote" those answers (perhaps all the answers) that provided you with useful information.  Once you've had a chance to take in all the answers to your question, you are encouraged to "accept" the answer that best solves your problem, by clicking the check mark next to the question.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas but I am not sure it is what you want as output.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mbox D^{\frac 1 2}_{mm^\prime}=\begin{array}{r | r r c}
\mbox{\backslashbox[11mm]{\scriptsize$m$}{\scriptsize$m^{\prime\prime}$}}& \frac 1 2 & - \frac 1 2 & \\ \hline
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}\frac 1 2 & a & b & \\[1ex]
-\frac 1 2 & c & d & 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

First I use the `diagbox` package and not the `slashbox` because due to license issues `slashbox` is not any more available in the TeXLive distribution. I used `\scriptsize` for the two values in the split cell in order to reduce the space needed and the risk of collision with a line. I also specified the length of the `backslashbox` line to get it as small as possible without any collision. Finally I removed the `setspace` package and the `doublespacing` setting in order to get rid of the extra space it induced in the first row. To keep it clean I have added some extra space for the following rows.

[image: Output]